# Firebase: Email verification link always expired even though verification works

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to set up an email verification flow in my project, but I can't seem to get it right.

How my flow works now is the user enters their credentials (email and password), which are used to create a new firebase user. Then, once that promise is resolved, it sends an email verification link to the new user that was created. The code looks like this:

```
async createUser(email: string, password: string) {
    try {
      console.log("Creating user...");
      const userCredentials = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        auth,
        email,
        password
      );
      console.log("Successfully created user");
      const { user } = userCredentials;
      console.log("Sending email verification link...");
      await this.verifyEmail(user);
      console.log("EMAIL VERIFICATION LINK SUCCESSFULLY SENT");
      return user;
    } catch (err) {
      throw err;
    }
  }

  async verifyEmail(user: User) {
    try {
      sendEmailVerification(user);
    } catch (err) {
      throw err;
    }
  }
```

The link is sent through fine, but once I press on it, I'm redirected to a page that says this:

[image]

Strangely, the user's email is verified after this, in spite of the error message displayed. Any idea why this is happening?

**Update:**
I managed to figure it out. The email provider I'm using is my university's, and it seems to be preventing the verification link from working properly. I did try with my personal email to see if that was the case, but I wasn't seeing the verification link appearing there. I eventually realized that it was because it was being stored in the spam folder. It's working on other email providers, though, ideally, I'd want it to work on my university's email provider (the emails that users sign up with are supposed to be exclusively student emails). Any ideas how I could resolve this?

Comment: Does your email verification link act on a GET request? If so, I'd bet your email provider's antivirus/malware protection is accessing the URL to check it.

Comment: @ceejayoz Do you mean, is an email verification link sent in response to a get request? It's possible it's the email provider (I'm using my student email, which is likely protected by some extra security mechanisms). I'm trying with my personal email, but for some reason, I'm not receiving the link on there. Weird.

Comment: @ceejayoz Ahhh, I figured it out. It is indeed the email provider causing the issue. It's my university email, and I'm guessing it's somehow intercepting the verification link. Not too sure how to resolve this. Then I found that the reason I wasn't seeing the verification link on my personal email is because it was being registered as spam...

Comment: The usual fix for this is to have the verification page have a form that auto-submits a POST request that actually does the verification. Your email provider's bots won't execute that code.

Comment: How I understand this would be done is a link is sent to the user in their email to redirect them back to a verification page on the website, which then auto submits a post request using firebase's authentication API to verify the user? Though, how can I send them a custom link? And shouldn't the URL include some form of identification, confirming that the user did indeed come from the verification link? Excuse me if I'm being a bit daft. I've never dealt with user authentication before.

Comment: *firebaser here* 

@AlePouroullis Great to hear that you figured it out with the help from ceejayoz. 

Our systems don't verify upon a GET request to the link in the mail, but instead render a widget into the page that then makes the an API request that performs the actual validation. So whatever system you have at uni, it seems to be doing quite a bit of work.

Can you post your findings as an answer, so I can upvote that - and others are more likely to find it?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Oh wow, seems they've got a pretty hectic system in place. Will do. I'm just currently coming up with my own custom method for handling user authentication, and then once I come up with something that works, I'll post the result as an answer. I'm thinking of creating a verification page on my website at a path like someUrl/authenticate, and then include the parameters for authentication on there in the link. Then, I'll add an event listener to the document on the loading of the content, and manually parse the URL to verify the user (from custom email action handlers docs.)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Sorry for getting around to it late. Just posted the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I eventually figured out that the issue was with my email provider. I was using my student email, which the university provides, and I imagine they've placed rigorous measures in place to secure them as much as possible. I have no idea what was preventing it from working, but I managed to figure out a workaround.

In brief, I changed the action URL in the template (which can be found in the console for your Firebase project in the Authentication section, under the Templates tab) to a route on my website titled /authenticate. I created a module to handle email verification. Included in it is a function that parses the URL, extracting the `mode` (email verification, password reset, etc.), `actionCode` (this is the important one. It stores the id that Firebase decodes to determine if it's valid), `continueURL` (optional), and `lang` (optional).

```
export const parseUrl = (queryString: string) => {
  const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  const mode = urlParams.get("mode");
  const actionCode = urlParams.get("oobCode");
  const continueUrl = urlParams.get("continueUrl");
  const lang = urlParams.get("lang") ?? "en";
  return { mode, actionCode, continueUrl, lang };
};
```

I created another method that handles the email verification by applying the `actionCode` from the URL using Firebase's `applyActionCode`.

```
export const handleVerifyEmail = async (
  actionCode: string,
  continueUrl?: string,
  lang?: string
) => {
  try {
    await applyActionCode(auth, actionCode);
    return { alreadyVerified: false };
  } catch (err) {
    if (err instanceof FirebaseError) {
      switch (err.code) {
        case "auth/invalid-action-code": {
          return { alreadyVerified: true };
        }
      }
    }
    throw err;
  }
};
```

The `auth/invalid-action-code` error seems to be thrown when the user is already verified. I don't throw an error for it, because I handle this differently to other errors.

Once the user presses the verification link, they're redirected to the /authenticate page on my website. This page then handles the email verification by parsing the query appended to the route. The URL looks something like this `http://localhost:3000/authenticate?mode=verifyEmail&oobCode=FLVl85S-ZI13_am0uwWeb4Jy8DUWC3E6kIiwN2LLFpUAAAGDUJHSwA&apiKey=AIzaSyA_V9nKEZeoTOECWaD7UXuzqCzcptmmHQI&lang=en`
Of course, in production, the root path would be the name of the website instead of localhost. I have my development environment running on port 3000.

Once the user lands on the authentication page, I handle the email verification in a `useEffect()` hook (Note: I'm using Next.js, so if you're using a different framework you might have to handle changing the URL differently):

```
  useEffect(() => {
    verifyEmail();

    async function verifyEmail() {
      const { actionCode } = parseUrl(window.location.search);
      if (!actionCode) return;
      router.replace("/authenticate", undefined, { shallow: true });
      setLoadingState(LoadingState.LOADING);
      try {
        const response = await handleVerifyEmail(actionCode!);
        if (response.alreadyVerified) {
          setEmailAlreadyVerified(true);
          onEmailAlreadyVerified();
          return;
        }
        setLoadingState(LoadingState.SUCCESS);
        onSuccess();
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        onFailure();
        setLoadingState(LoadingState.ERROR);
      }
    }
  }, []);
```

It first checks if there is an action code in the URL, in case a user tries to access the page manually.
The `onSuccess`, `onFailure`, and `onEmailAlreadyVerified` callbacks just display toasts. `loadingState` and `emailAlreadyVerified` are used to conditionally render different responses to the user.